# Mysql select operation matching different urls (common section), updating old rows

Tags: mysql, select, match

I'm in the middle of figuring out the way to transfer old urls to a new table - but it's not that simple.

Background: after importing the databases some of the files are stored in so called "legacy section". Fortunately for me, they work because they were imported properly and they are listed in a different table called "legacy". Somehow though script I'm using thought that it would be better to link to external old server to show those files. Right now there is now way for me to change that behaviour other than edit the Mysql manually.

**tl;dr**:

table after import: links to external server which will disappear after few weeks from now.

legacy table: files were pulled from old server, stored on the new one, and are just listed there, nothing else.

---

```
CREATE TABLE Resources
    (
     res_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     res_type varchar(255),
     res_cat varchar(255),
     res_name varchar(255),
     res_url varchar(255)
    );

INSERT INTO Resources
    (res_type, res_cat, res_name, res_url)
VALUES
    ('url', 'BLOG', 'External resource', 'http://path/12/BLOG/GOT/IN/Blog_ASK_M1L2_At_Secret.doc'),
    ('url', 'CORE', 'External resource', 'http://path/82/DOC/CORE/CORE_DOC_Over_Secret.doc'),
    ('url', 'HACK,JIG', 'External resource', 'http://path/53/HACK/JIG/HACK_JIG_Secret.pdf'),
    ('url', 'TEMPLATE', 'Internal resource', 'http://path/14/Documents/TEMPLATE/TEMPLATE_change.doc'),
    ('url', 'US,AUG', 'External resource', 'http://path/19/US/AUG/US_AUG_file.avi');

CREATE TABLE Legacy
    (
     res_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     res_type varchar(255),
     res_cat varchar(255),
     res_name varchar(255),
     res_url varchar(255)
    );

INSERT INTO Legacy
    (res_type, res_cat, res_name, res_url)
VALUES
    ('url', 'JOUR', 'Internal resource', 'http://website/22/JOUR/GOT/IN/Jour_In_M1L2_At_Secret.doc'),
    ('url', 'TEMPLATE', 'Internal resource', 'http://website/46/TEMPLATE/Template_Ever_Secret.doc'),
    ('url', 'INS', 'Internal resource', 'http://website/89/INS/INS_Secret.pdf'),
    ('url', 'IT,OL', 'Internal resource', 'http://website/98/Course_Doc/IT/OL/change.doc'),
    ('url', 'AST,JBP', 'Internal resource', 'http://website/185/file.php/AST/file.avi');
```

---

The categories are different on so many levels and the system ads it's own prefixes, that I have no option to use the categories, the id's or any other things that would be too obvious. I thought about this:

```
select if(
    length(substring_index(substring_index(res_url, '_', -3), '/', -1))<10,
    substring(res_url, -20),
    substring_index(substring_index(res_url, '_', -3), '/', -1))
    as LEGACY 
    from Legacy;
```

which with real files (where there are a lot of '_' in the file names, and a lot of categories) would gives us:

- M1L1_InfoSheet_GrantDonations.docx
- A_Hydropump_config.pdf
- HemotologyAndHemostasis.pdf
- KnowledgeCenter2.png
- OXYGENATION_WELDING_.pdf

But I don't know if that could be used in the process of searching.

**What I was thinking was, find the file names, somehow compare them (they are ALWAYS different) and just move the urls from the Legacy to Resources automatically**. That would solve everything for me. If there would be some problems, I can just find the urls with the "path" inside (domain name is different) and just do this manually. But doing 80% of the work would be awesome. I have nearly 4 years of posts there.

Any inside would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!